# Why are custom headers from response header not displaying in Angular (CORS)?

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot

When trying to log response.headers.keys() when using CORS, it only displays the following headers:
[
"cache-control",
"content-type",
"expires",
"pragma"
]

but when in non-cors, it displays the headers which we need.

Already tried to add **Access-Control-Expose-Headers** to our nginx config but it still didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.